# How to return the matching results from Array of object based on an array of input values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array of objects like below

```
var item = [
    { "name": "John", "age": 30, "city": "New York1" },
    { "name": "John1", "age": 31, "city": "New York2" },
    { "name": "John2", "age": 32, "city": "New York3" },
    { "name": "John3", "age": 31, "city": "New York3" }
]
```

What I want is to get some of the age from this array of objects which has age property value 
in `[30,31]`

So basically the input will be an array of integers like `var ageArray=[30,31];`

Example :

Input : `[30,31]`

Output : Sum of the `age` of the below objects

```
 { "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York1"},
 { "name":"John1", "age":31, "city":"New York2"},
 { "name":"John3", "age":31, "city":"New York3"}
```

So here it will be

```
92
```

I have tried to use filter for this but not sure how can i use `filter` with contains

What I have tried is

```
var result = item .filter(obj => {
                    return obj.age..includes(ages);
                })
```

Can someone help me to resolve this ?

Comment: you want elements or addition of age ?

Comment: @CodeManiac addition of age is enough now

Comment: its `sum` or some

Comment: Mhmm where are the attempts you tried tho? Cuz you're basically just asking for someone to do it fully for you, which isn't how SO works, but I'm sure you're aware of that ;-)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I have tried using filters, I have mentioned it in the code , i didnt include the code that i have tried thats all

Comment: You should, so people would try to fix the code you've tried and help tell you what you did wrong. Cheers!

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy sure i will add my effort in the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const items = [
{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York1"},
{ "name":"John1", "age":31, "city":"New York2"},
{ "name":"John2", "age":32, "city":"New York3"},
{ "name":"John3", "age":31, "city":"New York3"}]


const ages = [30, 31];
const res = items.reduce((sum, {age})=>{
  return sum + (ages.includes(age) ? age : 0);
}, 0);

console.log(res);
```

Modified for names:

```js
const items = [
{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York1"},
{ "name":"John1", "age":31, "city":"New York2"},
{ "name":"John2", "age":32, "city":"New York3"},
{ "name":"John3", "age":31, "city":"New York3"}]


const names = ["John", "john1"].map(n=>n.toLowerCase());
const res = items.reduce((sum, {name, age})=>{
  return sum + (names.includes(name.toLowerCase()) ? age : 0);
}, 0);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: one doubt how can i do the same if the inputs are name example like ["john","john1"]?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV yes, simply change `sum += age` to `sum += 1` ... if you wish to count the occurences of the names.

Comment: not exactly. the inputs will be array of names and based on that i need to filter and get the sum of age

Comment: so reduce((sum, {age,name})if(ages.includes(name)){
    sum += age;
  } this is enough right ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce)

```js
var item= [{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York1"},{ "name":"John1", "age":31, "city":"New York2"},{ "name":"John2", "age":32, "city":"New York3"},{ "name":"John3", "age":31, "city":"New York3"}]

var ageArray=[30,31];


let op = item.reduce((o,c)=>{
  if( ageArray.includes(c.age) ) 
   { o+=c.age }
  return o;
},0)

console.log(op)
```

Comment: one doubt how can i do the same if the inputs are name example like ["john","john1"]?

Answer (score 3):

You could use three steps

1. get only the ages
2. filter the ages with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
3. add remaining values

```js
var items = [{ name: "John", age: 30, city:" New York1" }, { name: "John1", age: 31, city: "New York2" }, { name: "John2", age: 32, city: "New York3" }, { name: "John3", age: 31, city: "New York3" }],
    ageArray = [30, 31],
    result = items
        .map(({ age }) => age)
        .filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(ageArray))
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(result);
```

A slightly different approach for different keys to filter and to add.

```js
var items = [{ name: "John", age: 30, city:" New York1" }, { name: "John1", age: 31, city: "New York2" }, { name: "John2", age: 32, city: "New York3" }, { name: "John3", age: 31, city: "New York3" }],
    names = ['John', 'John2'],
    result = items
        .filter((s => ({ name }) => s.has(name))(new Set(names)))
        .map(({ age }) => age)
        .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: one doubt how can i do the same if the inputs are name example like ["john","john1"]?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV, why not?

Comment: like i need to get the sum of age and the input will be array of names. can you please guide me to do the same too ?

Comment: oh, i see, you want some johns and the sum of ages of them, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to do this in one line:

```js
const item = [{name:"John",age:30,city:"New York1"},{name:"John1",age:31,city:"New York2"},{name:"John2",age:32,city:"New York3"},{name:"John3",age:31,city:"New York3"}]
 ,ageArray = [30,31]
 ,total = item.reduce((sum, {age})=> sum += ageArray.includes(age) ? age : 0, 0);

console.log(total)
```

Comment: one doubt how can i do the same if the inputs are name example like ["john","john1"]?

Comment: `item.reduce((sum, {name, age})=> sum += ageArray.includes(name) ? age : 0, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

```
const items = [
   { "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York1"},
   { "name":"John1", "age":31, "city":"New York2"},
   { "name":"John2", "age":32, "city":"New York3"},
   { "name":"John3", "age":31, "city":"New York3"}
];
const ages = [30,31];
const result = items.filter(o => ages.find(o2 => o.age === o2)).map(o3 => o3.age);
console.log(result)
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
console.log(result.reduce(reducer))
```